# Bold siuntix's function \num{} in math environment

Tags: equations, environments, siunitx, bold

I am looking for a way to make the `\num` function displayed in bold when used inside a `\begin{equation}`. Using `\mathbf` and `\boldmath` doesn't work (as `boldmath` makes the entire equation bold and should be used before instead of inside the environment) and the only thing that does, is using `\bfseries` which of course produces errors in math mode. So how could this work:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

    \sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
    \begin{equation}
       V= \frac{0,0003257}{150\cdot 99,96}= \mathbf{\num{2.1723e-8}}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Preferably without declaring new commands.

Comment: What do you have against declaring new commands?

Comment: I try to use the following rules: 1. Make do with least amount of writing, 2. If there is a built-in command, use it (to keep the preamble tidy). If there isn't such an option then comes a new command. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

siunitx has never detected \mathbf. But you can change the font by setting the math-rm-key:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}


    \begin{equation}
       V= \frac{0,0003257}{150\cdot 99,96}= \num[math-rm=\mathbf]{2.1723e-8}
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Would it be possible to somehow include units as opposed to writing: `V= \frac{0,0003257}{150\cdot 99,96}= \num[math-rm=\mathbf]{2.1723e-8} \mathbf{mm^3}`?

Comment: ? Why don't you use \SI in this case? `\SI[math-rm=\mathbf]{2.1723e-8}{\milli\meter\cubed}` works fine for me.

Comment: Quicker to write, especially if you have a lot of equations ...

Comment: In the long run 5 or 10 more characters to type are not so important.